# List Comprehension - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying iterate over lists in Python, but can't do it in an economic and pythonic way.

I can do in one dimension list:

```
api_time = ['hour', 'time']

text = 'What time is it?'
request = [r for r in api_time if r in text]
```

This outputs `'time'`, which is correct.

But when I start using two dimension list, I can't do it in **one sentence**.

```
api_time = ['hour', 'time']
api_weather = ['clime', 'rain']

apis = [api_time, api_weather]
```

How can I check this in **one sentence**?

Comment: Are you asking how to add `list`s? `apis =  api_time + api_weather` ?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel

Comment: `request = [r for r in (api_time + api_weather) if r in text]`

Comment: Dupe seems a little premature to me. I'm not convinced he wants to flatten the lists. He may need to know which parts of each individual list match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a double [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> api_time = ['hour', 'time']
>>> api_weather = ['clime', 'rain']
>>>
>>> apis = [api_time, api_weather]
>>> text = 'What time is it?'
>>> [r for api in apis for r in api if r in text]
['time']
```

Or a simple list addition instead of nested lists:

```
>>> [r for r in api_time + api_weather if r in text]
['time']
```

Comment: Probably would have been a better option to help close it as a dupe.

Comment: I think their mistake was making nested `list`s in the first place, no need to flatten them if they just concatenate the lists @idjaw

Comment: This is what I wanted, thank you. This is faster than two nested for loops?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Right. Are you saying that maybe it is not a dupe, but instead provide a different solution?

Comment: @idjaw I'm saying what Eric just added in the edit, I'm not sure it's worth re-opening though, there is another dupe somewhere no doubt

Comment: The list addition is not viable cause the objective is increase the number of apis.